# Compact null and emptyness check in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I have a null and not empty check:

```
myLocalVariable: String? = null
//..
if (item.data.propertyList !== null && item.data.propertyList!!.isNotEmpty()) {
    myLocalVariable = item.data.propertyList!![0]
}
```

I don't like the `!!`-Operators and I bet there is more beautiful and compact Kotlin way?

PROPOSAL1:

```
item.data.propertyList?.let {
     if (it.isNotEmpty()) myLocalVariable = it[0]
}
```

Still I have `?.let` and another `if` clause encapsulated.

PROPOSAL2:

```
fun List<*>?.notNullAndNotEmpty(f: ()-> Unit){
    if (this != null && this.isNotEmpty()){
        f()
    }
}
```

Here, it is still not compact, but when used several times, might be helpful. Still I dont know how to access the non empty list:

```
item.data.propertyList.notNullAndNotEmpty() {
    myLocalVariable = ?
}
```

Comment: I'd really suggest writing the code differently to avoid the local `var`. Why not initialize it directly with the correct value by using an expression? See @IvoBeckers's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the easiest and most compact way, without the need of any if-checks is to just do:

```
myLocalVariable = item.data.propertyList?.firstOrNull()
```

if you want to prevent overwriting in the case of `null` you could do it like this:

```
myLocalVariable = item.data.propertyList?.firstOrNull() ?: myLocalVariable
```

Answer (score 3):

There is the built in [`isNullOrEmpty`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/is-null-or-empty.html) method:

```
if (!item.data.propertyList.isNullOrEmpty()) {
    // provided that propertyList is a val, you do not need !! here
    myLocalVariable = item.data.propertyList[0]
    // otherwise, use "?."
    // myLocalVariable = item.data.propertyList?.get(0)
}
```

Comment: Instead of negating the result, you might find it more readable to define your own `fun Collection<*>?.isNotNullOrEmpty() = this != null && !isEmpty()`.

Comment: @gidds Wouldn't that cause the `item.data.propertyList[0]` part to require additional null handling, unless you use the experimental contracts API?

Comment: Ah yes… good spot. (It's a shame we don't yet have a fully-available contracts implementation — nor, even better, automatic detection of that sort of thing by the compiler so that explicit contracts weren't needed.)

Comment: @gidds also I find the suggested name `isNotNullOrEmpty` ambiguous: it sounds true for empty collections. Probably it should read `isNotNullNorEmpty` or `isNotNullAndNotEmpty`. Maybe even simpler: `isNotEmpty` - can't be null in this case anyway.